# Ошибка миграции

Tags: php, laravel

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_image_id_foreign` foreign key (`image_id`) references `file` (`id`))
```

Таблица `users`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            ...
            $table->integer('image_id');
            ...
        });

        Schema::table('users', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('image_id')
                ->references('id')->on('file');
        });
    }
```

Таблица `file`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('file', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            ...
        });
    }
```

Я неправильно прописал fk?
Изначально хотел связать таблицу `users` и `files`, чтобы присваивать пользователю картинку (аватар).

Comment: Таблицы Файлов скорее всего нету в момент когда создается таблица пользователей, сделай  миграцию с ключом после миграции с таблицей файлов

Comment: Можно ли сделать миграцию для определенных таблиц? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations здесь не нашел. Или просто поудалять таблицы без ключей, и сперва поднять с ключами, потом создать те, которые без?

Comment: Еще как вариант рассматриваю изменить время создания таблицы в названии файла таблицы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Распишу чуть подробнее:
Проблема в том, что вы создаете ссылку на таблицу которой нету, да вы можете поменять время создания (название файла) тех таблиц, что б они стояли выше, но думаю это не очень эстетично, у вас будут появляться все новые связки и вам все время делать `migrate:refresh` ?

Плюс в итоге можно запутаться что, когда, зачем делалось, поэтому логично делать так:

1) Создаете миграцию с таблицей на которое должно ссылаться поле, в вашем примере создаете таблице files:  `class CreateFilesTable() extends Migration{...}`

2) Затем создаете еще одну миграцию с "говорящим" названием, например add_filed_file_to_users_table и в ней создаете ваше поле file_id и затем описываете ссылку

```
class AddFiledFileIdToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('file_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('file_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('files')
                  ->onDelete('set null');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('users_file_id_foreign');
        });

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('file_id');
        });
    }
}
```

Это облегчит в последствии несколько проблем, вы всегда сможете вспомнить как развивались события, ну и в случае чего легко откатиться назад.

Comment: Не совсем понял 2 пункт. Грубо говоря, создаю таблицу, в которой будет только связь двух полей из двух таблиц?

Comment: Ща пример приведу

Comment: Ключ, по моему нужно  отдельно удалять от поля, точно не помню :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!